# Azure Logic App refuses to process EDIFACT D96B

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, edifact

Trying to decode an EDIFACT IFTSTA D96b file from a partner, receiving the error below. Schema is deployed. UNT count looks right, control number matches UNH.

"Error encountered during parsing. The Edifact transaction set with id '409400001' contained in functional group with id '4094', in interchange with id '4095', with sender id '{SENDER}', receiver id '{RECEIVER}' is being suspended with following errors:
Error: 1 (Miscellaneous error)
70: Error: 2 (Miscellaneous error)
71: Transaction Set or Group Control Number Mismatch
Error: 3 (Miscellaneous error)
29: Invalid count specified at interchange, group, or message levels"

Flatfile:
UNA:+.? 'UNB+UNOA:1+{removed}:ZZZ+{removed}:ZZZ+171003:0138+4095'UNG+IFTSTA+{removed}+{removed}+171003:0138+4094+UN+D:96B'UNH+409400001+IFTSTA:D:96B:UN'BGM+44'DTM+184:20171003013824-05:303'TSR+++3+11'RFF+ACL:0013000059'RFF+AGR:085'RFF+AAZ:DNZA'RFF+AF:CX'RFF+AWB:2TO8132'RFF+AHC:NA'LOC+5+SJU:::SAN JUAN, PR+Z4'LOC+8+ICN:::INCHEON, KOREA+Z4'FTX+AAB++INCO-TERM+CPT:INCHEON AIRPORT'FTX+PMD+++A'CNI+1'CNT+9:1'STS+1+21:::DPTD+62:::AIRC+62:::NOAP+62:::NOAP+62:::NOAP'RFF+IL:0013000059_2017SEP28_SAPQ96US'DTM+171:201710021255-04:303'NAD+IM+{removed}+++NONE+SEOCHO-GU,SEOUL+00++KR'NAD+FW+23637+{removed}+++{removed}+PA'EQD+ULD'MEA+WT+AAB+LBS:68.5'MEA+WT+G+KGS:31.1'MEA+VOL+AAW+I:000000015625'UNT+26+409400001'UNE+1+4094'UNZ+1+4095'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that you have UNG segment in the message. Did you provide the UNG2.1 and UNG2.2 while configuring the schema settings in the agreement.

[You should have the UNG2.1 and UNG2.2 in the schema settings as shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fY7VY.png)

If you still face issues after adding the UNG2.1 and UNG2.2 in the agreement schema settings, Please share your logic app Id with me @ rarayudu@microsoft.com. we will take a look and respond back.

Comment: We did not originally, but Azure support eventually got back to us and provided that same info. Thank you for answering here as well!